# Performance da Query - HELP

Tags: sql, query, oracle, desempenho

Estou fazendo uma *query*, porém estou aprendendo agora. Tem como melhorar a performance dessa query?

```
select a.COD_EMPRESA, b.Dat_pagamento
from SAS_EMPRESA a
full outer join SAS_ITEM_PAGO b on (a.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || a.COD_EMPRESA = b.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || b.COD_EMPRESA)
Where a.COD_GRUPO= 'BOT1' and
TO_CHAR(b.Dat_pagamento,'YYYYMM') BETWEEN 201601 AND 201711
```

Comment: você sabe o prq esta usando o full outer join ?

Comment: e o que queria fazer com o (a.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || a.COD_EMPRESA = b.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || b.COD_EMPRESA)

Comment: TROQUE (a.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || a.COD_EMPRESA = b.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || b.COD_EMPRESA) POR (a.COD_PREF_EMPRESA = b.COD_PREF_EMPRESA AND a.COD_EMPRESA = b.COD_EMPRESA)
Where a.COD_GRUPO= 'BOT1' and

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Não sei o porque estou usando esse comando, procurei na internet, e fiz uns testes, esse foi o que retornou os dados que eu preciso.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza  o código é assim: 

select a.*, b.*
from SAS_EMPRESA 
full outer join SAS_ITEM_PAGO b on (a.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || a.COD_EMPRESA = b.COD_PREF_EMPRESA || b.COD_EMPRESA)
where a.COD_GRUPO = 'BOT1' and 
TO_CHAR(b.Dat_pagamento,'YYYYMM') BETWEEN 201601 AND 201711

São duas tabelas GRANDES. Na empresas tem os dados e na item_pago os códigos. Vou retornar Códigos e Dados, em um período determinado. O código de empresa é separado em dois campos: COD_PREF e COD_EMPRESA, é preciso achar  empresa com a combinação dos dois campos.

É possível melhorar a performance dessa query?